# Rename a file to swap extensions in Unix

Tags: bash, unix

I have a bunch of files which are copied by "mv --backup=t source destination". So these files are in format `*.*.~[0-9]~`
For example,

```
some_file_name.pdf.~1~
some_file_name.pdf.~2~
another_file_name.docx.~1~
another_file_name.docx.~2~
```

Now, I would like to rename all such files so that the backup extension number came before the actual extension. Like

```
some_file_name_1.pdf
some_file_name_2.pdf
another_file_name_1.docx
another_file_name_2.docx
```

Is there a way to do in Unix using shell?
Any thoughts would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Apparently (comments to answers) the example filenames are different from the actual files. Please update the question to reflect the reality.

Comment: Hey @JamesBrown: Could you please suggest the update? I didn't get you.

Comment: `CR_71050_5.3.17.pdf.~1~` is not `some_file_name_1.pdf` as you need to chop it up by the periods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using BASH regex directives you can do this:

```
for f in *~; do
   [[ $f =~ ^(.+)\.([^.]+)\.~([0-9]+)~$ ]] &&
   echo mv "$f" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}_${BASH_REMATCH[3]}.${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
done
```

**Output:**

```
mv CR_71050_5.3.17.pdf.~1~ CR_71050_5.3.17_1.pdf
mv another_file_name.docx.~1~ another_file_name_1.docx
mv another_file_name.docx.~2~ another_file_name_2.docx
mv some_file_name.pdf.~1~ some_file_name_1.pdf
mv some_file_name.pdf.~2~ some_file_name_2.pdf
```

Once you're satisfied, you can remove `echo` before `mv`

Comment: This is not working for this file
`CR_71050_5.3.17.pdf.~1~`

Comment: How about this: `[[ $f =~ ^(.+)\.(.+)\.~(.+)~ ]]` ?

Comment: what about `mv "$f" "${f/%.~[0-9]*~}"`

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul: No that won't work because renamed files need last digit  added before extension.

Comment: ok i understand in this case it's easier to use bash regexp otherwise it needs more variable twiddling  `f1=${f%.\~*\~};n=${f##*.\~};echo ${f1%.*}_${n%\~}.${f1##*.}`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 awk -F~ '{ split($1,splt,".");system("mv "$0" "splt[1]"_"$2"."splt[2]) }'
```

We are essentially splitting the filenames on ~ and then using awks split function to further split the text and then pass it to the system function to execute the mv command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use rename (it is available as a Debian package).

```
$ ls
file.pdf.~1~  file.pdf.~10~  file.pdf.~2~  file.pdf.~3~  file.pdf.~9~

$ rename 's/.pdf.~([0-9]+)~$/$1.pdf/' *.pdf.~*~
$ ls
file10.pdf  file1.pdf  file2.pdf  file3.pdf  file9.pdf
```